# How to change my timezone with gmdate method? PHP

Tags: php, date, timezone

i wanna change my timezone to GMT+3. But i dont know how to do it. I dont wanna change gmdate method btw. Thanks already.

```
    $meetingstamp = strtotime($meeting_date . " UTC");   
    $dtstart= gmdate("Ymd\THis\Z",$meetingstamp);
    $dtend= gmdate("Ymd\THis\Z",$meetingstamp+$meeting_duration);
    $todaystamp = gmdate("Ymd\THis\Z");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer:

```
$meetingstamp = strtotime($meeting_date); 
$dtstart = gmdate("Ymd\THis\Z", $meetingstamp);
$dtend = gmdate("Ymd\THis\Z", $meetingstamp+$meeting_duration);
$todaystamp = gmdate("Ymd\THis\Z",strtotime("+3 hours"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Timezone can't be changed with gmdate or date, these functions are only for formatting a timestamp (and gmdate() will always create a GMT datetime while date() will take the timezone setting into account).

You can set the timezone with "date_default_timezone_set()" function.

Use "strtotime" to convert a datetime to a UNIX timestamp (if the string doesn't contain timezone information, it will use the PHP timezone settings!)

example:

```
$dateString = '2016-07-22 12:00:00 GMT+3'; 
$timestamp = strtotime($dateString);
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles'); // GMT -7
$newDateString = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp);
echo $newDateString;
```

Will output "2016-07-22 02:00:00".

Comment: Actually i just want that this code $todaystamp = gmdate("Ymd\THis\Z"); shows GMT+3.

Comment: Then read documentation of the "date()" function, it describes all parameters you'd need. You'll be looking for "P"

Comment: Simply , when i print  $todaystamp it gives me 3 hours before my clock time. I dont want it. And according to my rest of codes i have to use gmdate